# How to remove zero in 1st postion of a mysql table column

Tags: mysql, leading-zero

I have a mysql table with a field called emp_no.
THe field is padded with zeros and I only want to remove the first zero.
i.e. '000000001' (9 characters)
     Trim to '00000001' (8 characters)

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to update your table `foo` try this statement:

`UPDATE foo SET emp_no = RIGHT(emp_no, 8)`

For further reading with regards to the `RIGHT` function, see here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right (thanks @Jingles117)

Comment: Above answer is correct, just wanted to add that the Right and Left functions are quite useful and you should familiarize yourself with them. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right
Another option without updating is a simple SELECT Right(emp_no, 8) from foo